# Problem in .htaccess file - RewriteCond with gzip deflate

Tags: .htaccess, optimization, server, cpanel

Compaction files with gzip does not work when you add the root folder redirection rules to the specific folder in my project. How can I use the 2 things?

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYDOMAIN.COM$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.MYDOMAIN.COM$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !portfoliobuild/
RewriteRule (.*) /portfoliobuild/$1 [L]
```